# Wordpress Orderby conditions

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am working on displaying a list of posts returned by a filter set, and I am trying to order the list by 2 conditions in DESC order.

**1st Condition:** I'd like to orderby the custom field 'date_study_was_published' (date format is yyyymmdd).

**2nd Condition:** If there is more than one post with the same 'meta_value_num' for the custom field ('date_study_was_published'), then the post with the more recent 'date' value should come first.

Here's my parameters:

```
$limit = 10;
$big = 999999999;
$params = array(    
   'post_type'      => 'trackedstudies',
   'posts_per_page' => $limit,
   'paged'          => $paged,
   'meta_key'       => 'date_study_was_published', 
   'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num date',
   'order'          => 'DESC',
);
```

The built in orderby functionality doesn't seem to be doing the job. Do I need to write a new function?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `,` seperator

```
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num , date',
```

Comment: It Doesn't seem to except a comma within the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Display pages ordered by 'meta_value_num' and 'date'. (meta_value_num is dominant):

```
'orderby' => 'date  meta_value_num',
```

Display posts sorted by menu_order with a fallback to post title, in a descending order:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array ( 'orderby' => 'menu_order title', 'order' => 'DESC' ) );
```

REf: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: Thanks for the response. I actually am using the space separator already, and I just tried reversing the order as you've suggested like this 'date  meta_value_num', and still, the it seems to be ignoring the DESC 'date' parameters...when you say meta_value_num is 'dominant', what exactly does dominant mean in this context?

Comment: Thanks for reference. I just checked it out, and I am seeing the notation about the fallback that you mentioned, but for some reason my orderby seems to not be accepting the parameters properly (as far as I can tell). It is showing them in the 'date' ASC order and I am asking for 'meta_value_num date' in DESC order....any ideas or past experiences that may shed light?

Comment: Anyone have any Ideas?